# Facets in SOLR using text not in document

Tags: solr, lucene, metadata, velocity, facet

I am indexing word document files in Apache SOLR and would like to use facets. Using Velocity, I'm able to use the facet fields and queries which appear as part of document meta data. I'm interested in using fields which are not part of Meta data as facet fields. Ex: Name is a field that does not appear in the document but I would like to use that as facet field. So what I would get is Facet field Name under which I'll have names like John, Bridget etc along with details of the number of documents in which these names (John, Bridget) appear. Please let me know if it is possible to index documents based on fields that are not part of meta data and how can the same be shown as part of facet fields.

Comment: It would be easier if you post your current schema and one or more sample of your documents

Comment: @freedev, the schema is the default schema that is generated when I created the core. I have not made any changes to the same. Also the documents (6 word documents) are handcrafted that have nothing but names like John Doe, Britney Spears, Maverick, Harry etc. I have made sure that "NAME" does not appear in any of the document.  Please let me know in case you require any further information from my side.

Comment: It is not clear how is your schema, even if you're using the default schema that is generate when you created the core. It is not clear if you're using a client or writing directly query via http. Usually all the fields in the document can be indexed and if they are indexed depends on how your collection is configured. Regarding the faceting I suggest to read [Solr Faceting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting)

Comment: @freedev, thanks for your suggestion regarding Faceting. But what I would like to know is, when I index documents (MS Word and PDF) SOLR indexes the same based on the meta data of the document. Along with the meta data indexing, is it possible to index the data on field which is not part of document meta data as well as the same is not found inside the document. In this case, I'm referring to a field called name which is not found in any document. Please let me know how I can attach the files like the managed-schema,solrconfig.xml and word documents that are used for indexing